# Wordpress: media library uploader (localhost) cannot upload files

Tags: linux, wordpress, localhost, media

I am on a KUbuntu 12.04 with Apache2, MySQL, PHP, vsftpd setup.
I have installed WordPress 3.8.1 for local (testing) purposes and everything seems to working fine expect the Media Uploader (both flash and browser).

When I try to upload an image or a PDF file, it stucks on Crunching... and never continues from this point, although the file is uploaded to "uploads" folder.
When I click on `Dashboard -> Media -> Library`, the file is there but when I try to insert it in a post or page the library is empty.

My settings are:
I did `usermod -a -G www-data myusername`
I've changed ownership and group recursively to `www` folder and subfolders and files with 755 permissions.

`Apache2 (/etc/apache2/envvars)`
`APACHE_RUN_USER= myusername`
`APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data`
tried everything here: `username:usergroup, www-data:www-data` (the default) with no success.

How can I fix this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you chmod the uploads directory?

```
chmod 777 uploads
```